# Как я могу программно определить частоту дискретизации файла WAV?

Tags: python, wav, vosk

Есть программа написанная на python, которая распознаёт текст с использованной библиотекой vosk. Для распознавания текста нужно передать частоту дискретизации и модель языка этой строкой : `KaldiRecognizer(model, 96000)`, где 96000 - это сама частота.
чтобы определить частоту дискретизации файла я использую следующий код:

```
with wave.open(r'a.wav', "rb") as wave_file:
    frame_rate = wave_file.getframerate()
    print(frame_rate)
```

НО! Практически во всех файлах он определяет частоту: 48000, для некоторых аудио файлов она почему-то не подходит и выводится какой-то бред а не текст (просто набор слов), тобиш vosk не правильно определяет текст в аудио, решается эта проблема ручной заменой частоты на нужную, постоянно необходимо подбирать её. в чём может быть проблема? до этого, преобразовывал аудио файл в онлайн конвертации. Хотелось бы автоматизировать процесс.

Answer (score 0):

**Полагаю, проблема в теории**

Может быть несколько причин, по которым ваш код неправильно определяет частоту дискретизации некоторых аудиофайлов:

**1. Неподдерживаемый аудиоформат:** Модуль wave, используемый в вашем коде, поддерживает только ограниченный набор аудиоформатов. Если аудиофайл, который вы пытаетесь открыть, находится в формате, который модуль не поддерживает, он может возвращать неправильную частоту. Возможно, вам потребуется использовать другой модуль, поддерживающий более широкий спектр аудиоформатов, например модуль [pydub](https://pypi.org/project/pydub/).

**2. Неправильная информация о заголовке:** Некоторые аудиофайлы могут содержать неправильную информацию о заголовке, которая не соответствует фактической частоте дискретизации. Это может произойти, когда файл создан неправильно или когда он конвертируется из одного формата в другой. В этом случае вам, возможно, потребуется вручную установить частоту дискретизации при передаче файла в библиотеку `Vosk`.

**3. Кодирование с переменной скоростью передачи данных (VBR):** Некоторые аудиофайлы могут иметь кодировку с переменной скоростью передачи данных, что означает, что скорость передачи данных изменяется по всему файлу. В этом случае частота, сообщаемая модулем wave, может быть неточной, и вам может потребоваться использовать другой метод для определения частоты дискретизации.

Чтобы автоматизировать процесс, вы можете попробовать использовать вышеупомянутый модуль [pydub](https://pypi.org/project/pydub/) для преобразования аудиофайлов в поддерживаемый формат с фиксированной частотой дискретизации перед передачей их в библиотеку `Vosk`. Вы также можете попробовать использовать модуль [mediainfo](https://pypi.org/project/pymediainfo/) для извлечения частоты дискретизации непосредственно из метаданных файла вместо того, чтобы полагаться на модуль wave.